# Laravel show records as flat array or single record

Tags: arrays, laravel

I have 2 column in my table setting
with the following values

```
KEY         VALUE

company     ABC 
phone       14344
address     Somerset City
```

I need to display this like a single record or a flatten
array in the view/blade page

something like

```
{{$sett->company}}
{{$sett->phone}}
```

or an array with lookup

```
{{$myarray('company')}}
{{$myarray('phone')}}
```

The idea is if I add another settings  like contact us email address
for my website I don't want to add another column.

I know this is achievable in controller by creating different variable
and executing different query but I'm kind of looking for some options here.

Thanks for the help really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$settings->pluck('value', 'key')` to get your result. Read more here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck